# start-dfs.sh throws port 22: connection timeout error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, openssh

I am trying to install hadoop on ubuntu in pseudo-distributed environment.

`start-dfs.sh` (gives me an error)

```
Starting namenodes on [10.1.37.12]

10.1.37.00: ssh: connect to host 10.1.37.12 port 22: Connection timed out

localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-superuser-datanode-superuser-Satellite-E45W-C.out

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]

0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-superuser-secondarynamenode-superuser-Satellite-E45W-C.out
```

I have added port 22 to firewall

jps output:

2562 DataNode

3846 Jps

2743 SecondaryNameNode

Can somebody help me understand, whats wrong here?

```
EXPORT HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p 22"' -- done
added port 22 to firewal("sudo ufw allow 22")
Tried stopping the firewall("sudo ufw disable")
run ssh -vvv 10.1.37.12 and share output
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.1.37.12 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.37.12 [10.1.37.12] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.1.37.12 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.1.37.12 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Seems to be related to firewall. Try stopping firewall

Comment: Tried stopping firewall, Still Getting error.                                               Starting namenodes on [10.1.37.12]
10.1.37.12: ssh: connect to host 10.1.37.12 port 22: Connection timed out
localhost: datanode running as process 2562. Stop it first.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 2743. Stop it first.

Comment: Can you run `ssh -vvv 10.1.37.12` and share output

Comment: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.1.37.12 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.37.12 [10.1.37.12] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.1.37.12 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.1.37.12 port 22: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `/etc/hosts` file, you need to mention the private ip address (within subnet range). The same has to be updated in **worker** file [image]